# Ubuntu boot black screen and message

Tags: boot, drivers

My pc with Ubuntu 16.04 was overheating and had 100% cpu usage, so to fix i tried to change from noveau nvidia drivers to the proprietary drivers. Now i can't boot into my desktop beucase i get a black screen with this message:

```
"/dev/sda8: clean, 241391/4235264 files, 7230305/16920576 blocks"
```

What is this? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

as far as the message you are getting it really isnt anything to do with your driver issue. it is just checking your disk for problems. whenever you boot this happens normally even on a fresh install. under normal conditions it will not find anything and you will just go ahead with booting.

what i suggest though for your driver problem, if it is that:
on boot select the "advanced options" and go into recovery mode.

here you can do things to work in your system. since this likely has to do with your installing the proprietary drivers what you want to do is go and select the root shell option so you can work in the command line.

then you can go back to your proprietary driver and select it, but add the `--uninstall` option to the end. this will uninstall it.

afterwards what you do is up to you. you can go back to the nouveau driver which if you blacklisted it and removed everything like you were suppose to then you need to undo the blacklisting and reinstall it. alternatively you can try to reinstall the proprietary driver. you will need to reboot though either way to see if things are working.

if things are still broken try going back to shell and using the "dpkg" option to try and fix any broken packages.